# Create a virtual Memory using Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, storage, virtual, android-sdcard

I want to basically create a virtual Memory like SD Card in my Android device running 8.0 and is rooted.

So basically all the other apps(Like File Browsers) should recognize it as a SD card where as it is just going to be a virtual memory.

And they should also recognize my Internal Memory.

Is this possible to achieve?

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259117/does-android-support-virtual-memory

Comment: @nyulan Thanks. Will have a look and update.

Comment: @nyulan Thanks for the answer and really sorry for the very much delayed reply. But your answer could not guide me with the steps to create a SD card using Internal Memory. Can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but it seems that you want to expose some of your device's virtual memory (RAM) as a virtual SD card.

Looking at how people attempted to address a different problem (see https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=948887), I infer that one way to do it would be:

- Create a "tmpfs" file system
- Mount it<sup>1</sup> at the location where Android would mount an regular external SD card.

<sup>(Sorry: no commands to copy and paste.  This kind of stuff could brick your device.  Anyone doing this should take responsibility for looking up and reading the manual ... so that they **understand** what they are doing themselves.)</sup>

The problem is that there is no standard that tells Android device manufacturers where SD cards should be mounted.  And apparently, different manufacturers put the cards in different places.  (The Android developer docs say that you shouldn't use hard-wired pathnames ...)

A couple of common patterns I have seen for SD card pathnames:

- There is often a "/sdcard" symlink that points to the place where the SD card or cards are actually mounted.
- The SD card file systems are often mounted within the "/mnt" tree.

You will need to investigate what happens on your device ...

---

<sup>1 - I would be cautious about making this a permanent mount to start with.  If this approach fails, you may need to reboot to recover.  If you made the mount permanent, there is a risk that you would not be able to boot.  I don't know if it is possible to recover from that.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I meant to use some of my Internal Storage as SD Card, which means without having a SD Card actually inserted I project as if a SD Card is actually inserted. By SD Card I mean SD Card is a removable storage. And Internal Storage is the storage where all the images, videos etc are stored and can be edited by a common user.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you just need to add some symlinks ... so that the internal storage is accessible via a path the the application *thinks* is in the SD card area.

Comment: Thanks. Since I am really new can you please guide on how to do that.

Comment: What?  Creating a symlink?  Use the `ln -s` command.  It should be explained by `man ln`.  (Did you see my *"sorry no copy-and-paste commands"* aside?  If you feel that you need a step-by-step guide, I think you should not be messing with this stuff!)

Comment: I think you are right, I would end up messing up with something. So will leave it for now till it is not very important. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create partition of SD Card from app on pc... for more please refer the link: [How to partition Storage](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/increase-internal-storage-space-of-android.html)

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look and update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and really sorry for the very much delayed reply. But your answer could not guide me with the steps to create a SD card using Internal Memory. Can you please elaborate your answer.